# like clause doesn't work as it said in MySQL SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, sql-like

I have a table, such as
create table table1(
name varchar(32),
);

And there's some data in it. When I select like this:
select * from table1 where name like 'Jack2%';

there will be Jack2.

But if I select like this:
select * from table1 where name like 'Jack[0-9]%';
there will be nothing;

And I also tried regexp to subsitute like, but it also didn't work!

What's wrong?

Comment: well, SQL spec does not handle regex like that

Comment: `LIKE` in SQL has nothing to do with regular expressions...

Comment: mysql uses regex this way http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've confused two different pattern-matching mechanisms.  SQL `LIKE` uses `%` to match anything and `_` to match any single character; it does not have anything like `[0-9]` to match a digit.  That looks like a character class from a regular expression.

Standard SQL has no support for regular expressions at all, but MySQL does - you just have to use `RLIKE` (or `REGEXP`, but that doesn't read as nicely IMO) instead of `LIKE`.  But that means that you have to replace the `%` with the regular-expression equivalent `.*`, too.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name RLIKE 'Jack[0-9].*';
```

Comment: Yes, As I have said you and Frank Bonnet are right!

Answer (score 1):

**[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90fb8c/2)**

**[MySQL REGEX](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/484/use-regular-expressions-in-mysql-select-statements/)**

```
select * from Table1 where `name` REGEXP 'Jack[0-9]'
```

Comment: Note that RLIKE and REGEXP are exact synonyms.

Comment: Well, thanks. The true reason is that % doesn't represent any text in regexp but it does in like. So we should substitute % with .*

Answer (score 1):

You can use RLIKE instead

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name RLIKE 'Jack[0-9].*';
```

And please note the the '%' operator won't work with RLIKE, you have to use a regular expression pattern like '.*' instead.

Comment: Note that `RLIKE` and `REGEXP` are exact synonyms.